# NSURLConnection to check periodic updates on the server

Tags: ios, ipad, nsurlconnection, nstimer

I have a function "downLoadButtonStatusSetter" which is called every 15 seconds with a timer.
It then calls sends "sendInstantGetInfoRequest" data to the server and checks whether the connection is available, and sets a flag.
The application is working properly, but gets into a busy state for a while when it fails to connect to the server.
How should i call these methods so that "It gets called every 15 seconds AND sets the flags even though it fails to connect to the server,
 without affecting the main execution of the program. I have tried a combination of thread callings , but cannot, please help.

The timer calling code:

```
updateCheckTimer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(downLoadButtonStatusSetter) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

ButtonStatusSetter Code:

```
-(BOOL) downLoadButtonStatusSetter
{

    [self sendInstantGetInfoRequest];
    if( instantGetInfoOffLineForButton)
        {
            //setbutton color etc....
        }
}

-(NSArray *)sendInstantGetInfoRequest
{

    NSString *getInfoURL=[SAGlobal getInfoURL];
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"username",@"password", nil];
    NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:SharedAppDelegatee.SAloginName, SharedAppDelegatee.SAloginPassword, nil];
    jsonManager = [[JsonRequestManager alloc] init];
    SAJSonResult* resultk=[jsonManager sendJsonAsPOSTData: keys AndValues:objects toURL: getInfoURL];
if(resultk.jsonError)
{
    instantGetInfoOffLineForButton=true;
}
else{
    instantGetInfoOffLineForButton=false;
}

return resultk.jsonResult;
```

}

The JSON request sending code:

```
-(SAJSonResult *) sendJsonAsPOSTData:(NSArray *) keys AndValues:(NSArray *) values toURL:(NSString *)anURL
{
////..................
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:anURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url1];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: jsonData];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&jsonError];
if (jsonError) {
   ..............
    return jResult;
}
else
{
   ...............

    return jResult;

}
}
}
```

Comment: You are initiating a synchronous request which will make the UI freeze until you get the response from the server and in case of poor connection it will freeze the UI until you get the response. You have to use asynchronous request if you dont want to make UI freeze.

Comment: @ioSGeek is it possible to use this synchronous request to execute on another thread while executing the normal main thread, with user activities etc..because i just want to set a flag, based on a single request and response which must be executed serially one after the other after execution. Eg:-REQUEST1->FINISHED(FAILED/SUCCESS)->SETFLAG->REQUEST1->..........->REQUEST1->....

Comment: What kind of flags are you going to set in case of failure and success?